# Can i use hibernate named query for large sql without creating entity class?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have a very large sql query (multiple joins-multiple tables)using which i am retrieving data from multiple tables using hibernate.The sql is kept in a constant java interface as a final string and i am using that in hibernate native sql to execute the query.

Now the query  can change.Can i use in as a named query in hibernate-mapping xml file without creating any entity class for that query.

```
List data= session.getNamedQuery("dummyQuery").list();
```

Is there any alternatine solution for this?I dont want to keep the large query in a java contant file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can absolutely do that. However if you want to map the returned result to POJOs, you'll have to use result set transformer.

Comment: while using name-query without any entity class i am getting an exception...no class name or entity name provided"

Comment: Can you post <sql-query> content for the query?